# UIAlertView message display

Tags: iphone, uialertview

I need to show one alert message like
“Are you sure? [Y/N] 
WARNING - This will reset scores.”

For this I am writing following lines of code:

```
 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
    [alert setMessage: NSLocalizedString(@"Are you sure?", nil)];
    [alert setTitle:@"WARNING - This will reset scores."];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Y"];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"N"];
    [alert setDelegate:self];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
```

By this I am getting the warning text at first and then the question and buttons. but I want that warning text to appear at last.
The flow will be like first question (Are you sure?), then two buttons(Y/N) and then warning text.Please help me to do this. I am struct at this. Please help.

Comment: Please follow the answer given below.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIAlertView *alert1= [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Are you sure?" message:@"Warning-This will reset scores." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Y",@"N", nil];
[alert1 show];
[alert1 release];
```

Just Use Simple init method !!

Answer (score 1):

You should Create Custom AlertView. Here is my custom AlertView code, you can just follow it to create your own required alertView. Perhaps It will help you.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Utility.h"

@interface AlertViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
{
    UITextView         *_sharingTextView;
}
- (void) showAlertViewWithTextView;
@end
```

And then in .m file

```
#import "AlertViewController.h"

@implementation AlertViewController

#define AlertViewIphoneInitFrame CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 100)
#define AlertViewIpadInitFrame CGRectMake(200, 50, 600, 200)
#define TextViewIphoneFrame CGRectMake(20, 50, 260, 80)
//#define TextViewIpadFrame CGRectMake(40, 100, 520, 160)
#define AlertViewIphonePresentFrame CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 200)
#define AlertViewIpadPresentFrame CGRectMake(200, 200, 600, 400)

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - Custom AlertView 
//Custom AlertView
- (void) showAlertViewWithTextView 
{
    UIAlertView *alert;
    if ([[Utility getCurrentDevice] isEqualToString:@"iPad"])
    {
         alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithFrame:AlertViewIpadInitFrame];
        _sharingTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:TextViewIphoneFrame];
    }
    else
    {
        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithFrame:AlertViewIphoneInitFrame];
        _sharingTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:TextViewIphoneFrame];
    }
    alert.title = @"History Application";
    alert.message = nil;
    alert.delegate = self;
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Return"];

    _sharingTextView.text = @"To share you events through tweets or facebook sharing you have to login, You can do so here or when trying to tweet or facebook share. You can also logout here";
    [_sharingTextView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18.0]];
    [_sharingTextView setEditable:NO];
    [alert addSubview:_sharingTextView];
    [alert show];
    [_sharingTextView release];
    [alert release];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{
}

// to set the alertView frame size.
- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView 
{
    if ([[Utility getCurrentDevice] isEqualToString:@"iPad"])
    {
        [alertView setFrame:AlertViewIpadPresentFrame];
    }
    else
    {
        [alertView setFrame:AlertViewIphonePresentFrame];
    }
    [alertView setFrame:AlertViewIphonePresentFrame];
    for ( UIView *views in [alertView subviews]) 
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",views);
        if (views.tag == 1) 
        {
            [views setFrame:CGRectMake(views.frame.origin.x+10, views.frame.origin.y+80, views.frame.size.width, views.frame.size.height)];
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (void)dealloc {
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You currently have the warning text as the title so it will show above the message. Change your setMessage to something like below:

```
NSString *fullMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\nWARNING - This will reset scores.", NSLocalizedString(@"Are you sure?", nil)];
[alert setMessage: fullMessage];
```

Comment: This will just change the warning text line number, but what I want to display is,. first "Are you Sure?", then two buttons(Y/N), then warning text.

Comment: Ah, you can't do that sort of layout with the built-in UIAlertView. You would have to create your own custom view for something like that (AFAIK).